# Get attribute parameters using jQuery or RegEx using UFT One

Tags: jquery, regex, hp-uft

I have a web Element with something like:

```
var params = new Object(); params.minValue=-2147483648; params.allowNegative="Y"; params.maxValue=2147483647; params.maxLength=11; params.allowLeadingZeros="N"; formatOnField(this,params,[formatInteger], arguments[0])
```

All I want to do is to get the value of `params.maxValue`.

I can get the whole attribute line if I do:

```
$("[id='xxx']").attr('onkeyup')
```

but is there anyway I can just get the params.maxValue? It seems the params.xxx are part of an array of parameters of the attribute so I thought it should be easy to just get that part params.maxValue?

Alternatively, if I can only get the whole attribute I can use regex matching:

```
params.maxValue=[^,]*?(\d+)
```

which returns 2147483647 but I cant get this to work inside UFT one as I have to use `Regex.Match(string, pattern).Value` or similar but UFT doesnt find the Regex Match function. I tried importing it:

```
Set re = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Text.RegularExpressions")
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You can append `yourFunction(params)` to the attribute value, then define that function yourself to do whatever you want with the argument and its properties, no? Also, do you have control over that web component? If yes, then do never write JS in `on...` attributes. Extract those to a function and add that as an event listener.